# Prove that $K = \cap_{g \in G} g^{-1}G_xg$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Relevant definitions:

> $$G_x = \{g \in G \mid \rho_g(x) = x\}$$

Question:

> Let $\rho: G \to S(X): g \mapsto \rho_g$ be a transitive group
>   action. Let $K := \ker \rho$. Then $K = \cap_{g \in G} g^{-1}G_xg$

My attempt (which I know is wrong, since I didn't use transitivity!):

> $\boxed{\supset}$
>
> Let $k \in \cap_{g \in G} g^{-1}G_xg$. Then, for all $g \in G$, there
>   exists $l \in G_x$ such that $k = g^{-1}lg$, such that $\rho_k =
>  \rho_{g^{-1}lg} = 1_X$, meaning that $k \in K$
>
> $\boxed{\subset}$
>
> Let $k \in K$ and $g \in G$. Then, consider the group element $h :=
> gkg^{-1}$. Then, we have $\rho_h(x) = x$, such that $h \in G_x$. Now,
>   it follows that $k = g^{-1}hk \in g^{-1}G_xg$ for any $g \in G$, as
>   desired.

Can someone point out where my mistake is? I am quite sure I made a mistake since I never used transitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't conclude that $\rho_k = 1_X$ just from what you've written.  However, it follows from the fact the $k = g^{-1} l g$ that $k \in G_{\rho_{g^{-1}}(x)}$.  Can you see how to use transitivity now?

The second part looks ok except for a typo (I guess you meant $k = g^{-1}h g \in g^{-1}G_xg$ instead of $k = g^{-1}h k \in g^{-1}G_xg$).

Comment: Ah I see where my mistake lies now. The x is fixed. Trying to see how to use the transitivity now.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Let me know if you get stuck again.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that. Will get back later to you :)

Comment: I still got stuck. I can't see how to use transitivity here. Transitivity just allows me to write $y = \rho_s(z)$ for a certain $s \in G$

Comment: You need to show that for each $y \in X$, $\rho_k(y)=y$ (or equivalently, that $k \in G_y$).  Note also that you get to pick $g \in G$.

Comment: I did not manage to find the correct answer. Can you provide it (must not be detailed). I will then accept your answer.

Comment: @Math_QED We already have $k \in G_{\rho_{g^{-1}}(x)}$.  By transitivity, you can choose $g \in G$ such that $k \in G_y$ for any $y \in X$.